# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'check_password'

Tags: django

I saw this question was asked many times already but it's not working for me. The problem is the `authenticate` method always returns None.

this is what i added in settings

```
# Custom User
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'account.CustomUser'

#Authentication backends
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

this is the `clean` method inside form class

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs=email_attr))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=password1_attr))
    
    class Meta:
        fields = ['email', 'password']

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cleaned_data = super(LoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')
        password = cleaned_data.get('password')
        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
        print(user)
        try:
            CustomUser.objects.get(email=email)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError({'email': 'Email is incorrect'})

        if not user.check_password(password):
            raise forms.ValidationError({'password': 'Password is incorrect!'})
        return cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
def loginView(request):
    template_name = "app/login.html"
    form = LoginForm()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form})
```

error i got

```
if not user.check_password(password):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'check_password'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[authenticate](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9a2a12d415e6d224797b0779c5af03deb8c45b0a/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L36-L49) already calls `check_password()` internally. If anything goes wrong, the function returns `None`, which seems to be the case when you're getting the error.

It's also recommended to not disclose in the error message if the problem is non-existing email or a wrong password. It's called [user enumeration](https://blog.rapid7.com/2017/06/15/about-user-enumeration/) and even though it's not a vulnerability itself, it can give a potential attacker info about your user accounts.